# How to prevent Mathematica 10 from instantly displaying hover menus?

Tags: front-end, options, menu

I recently updated to *Mathematica 10* in the hopes to get the most up to date function definitions and run time optimizations. Alas, along with the (hopefully significant) improvements (not so sure about that) came an infuriatingly annoying tendency of the program to instantly show a little clickable menu right on top of an expression as soon as I hover my mouse over it. This very much resembles cheap click-bait techniques of suspicious websites, where the screen jerks a little right before you click something, so that you end up clicking something entirely different that you never would have clicked otherwise. This led to numerous wrong clicks so far, which wasted my time on either bringing up the documentation or starting to compute a completely nonsensical sum from one to infinity. In short, I do not like to be hassled by the program to click on useless hover menus. Is there a way to delay the display of such hover menus by a few seconds, or disable them completely? I have explored the options menu a little but have not found a solution yet. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Preferences->Interface->Enable floating elements

Comment: Oh, yes, this does solve my problem. I guess the reason I did not find this post myself is because I was searching for "hover menus" instead of "pop-up windows". Now both titles are on stackexchange, which increases the probability for other users to find the answer right away.